# I'm trying to write a sort function in C but I'm pretty new at declaring functions and couldn't make it work

Tags: c, function

I'm learning how to declare functions and use them in C. I tried to write a brick sort algorithm in C but couldn't make it work. Algorithm itself works fine when I write everything inside the main function so I assume the problem is with how I tried to declare the function. As I said, I'm a newbie at this stuff so please excuse me if it is something obvious that I'm missing and thank you in advance for taking your time and helping me out. I really appreciate it.

**this is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n, i, a[100], temp, isSorted;

int brickSort(a[], n)
{
    isSorted=0;
    
    while(isSorted==0)
    {
        isSorted=1;
        
        for(i=0; i<=n-2; i=i+2)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=temp;
                isSorted=0;
            }
        }
        
        for(i=1; i<=n-2; i=i+2)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=temp;
                isSorted=0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the amount of numbers ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    
    return brickSort(a[], n);

    return 0;
}
```

**this is the error message I get**

```
 int brickSort(a[], n)
               ^
main.c:5:20: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘n’
 int brickSort(a[], n)
                    ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:53:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘brickSort’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return brickSort(a[], n);
            ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:53:24: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
     return brickSort(a[], n);
                        ^
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of text (the error message here) because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Text should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought it would be better that way. Is there a way to edit my question or do I need to resubmit it? Code itself is in text format, only the error message is an image if it makes a difference.

Comment: You can edit your question by using the "Edit" link below your question. You can also edit from here: [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the types of arguments to declare arguments like:

```c
int brickSort(int a[], int n)
```

And remove the extra `[]` from the function call like:

```c
return brickSort(a, n);
```

In this case, all variables are declared as global variables (not good design), so you actually won't need the arguments and you can remove them like:

```c
int brickSort(void)
```

```c
return brickSort();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the types of the parameters in the parameter list.

```
int brickSort(int a[], int n)
```